# Solution of the Legendre's ODE using Frobenius Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

This is the Legendre's differential equation given in my book:

$(1-x)^{2}\ddot{y}-2x\dot{y}+k(k+1)y=0$

I solved this equation by taking:

$y=x^{c}\{a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+.....+a_{r}x^{r}+.....\}$

Therefore, each term in the equation becomes (I deliberately didn't use the sum notation to see it clearly):

$k(k+1)y=k(k+1)a_{0}x^{c}+k(k+1)a_{1}x^{c+1}+k(k+1)a_{2}x^{c+2}+.....+k(k+1)a_{r}x^{c+r}+.....$

---

$-2x\dot{y}=-2ca_{0}x^{c}-2(c+1)a_{1}x^{c+1}-2(c+2)a_{2}x^{c+2}-.....-2(c+r)a_{r}x^{c+r}-.....$

---

$\ddot{y}=(c-1)ca_{0}x^{c-2}+c(c+1)a_{1}x^{c-1}+(c+1)(c+2)a_{2}x^{c}+.....+(c+r-1)(c+r)a_{r}x^{c+r-2}+.....$

---

$-x^{2}\ddot{y}=-(c-1)ca_{0}x^{c}-c(c+1)a_{1}x^{c+1}-(c+1)(c+2)a_{2}x^{c+2}-.....-(c+r-1)(c+r)a_{r}x^{c+r}-.....$

---

The indicial equation is $(c-1)ca_{0}x^{c-2}=0$. Therefore, there are two solutions for $c=0$ and $c=1$. Since,

$(c+r+2)(c+r+1)a_{r+2}+k(k+1)a_{r}-2(c+r)a_{r}-(c+r)(c+r-1)a_{r}=0$

general recurrence equation is as follows:

$a_{r+2}=\frac{[(c+r-k)(c+r+k+1)]a_{r}}{(c+r+2)(c+r+1)}$

There is no problem so far. But my book gives the following answer for $c=0$:

$y=a_{0}\left\{ 1-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}x^{2}+\frac{k(k-2)(k+1)(k+3)}{4!}x^{4}-.....\right\}$

This is only possible for $a_1=0$. But I can't see that. I will be very glad if anyone can show me why $a_1$ should be equal to zero when $c=0$.

### Answer:

I solved both for $c=0$ and $c=1$ as @Semiclassical suggested. For $c=0$, $a_1$ is **indeterminate** because of the term: $c(c+1)a_1x^{c-1}$ (It can be any value). Therefore, the solution is:

$u=a_{0}\left\{ 1-\frac{k(k+1)}{2!}x^{2}+\frac{k(k-2)(k+1)(k+3)}{4!}x^{4}-.....\right\} +a_{1}\left\{ x-\frac{(k-1)(k+2)}{3!}x^{3}+\frac{(k-3)(k-1)(k+2)(k+4)}{5!}x^{5}-.....\right\}$

For $c=1$, $a_1=0$ because of the term: $c(c+1)a_1x^{c-1}$, thus the solution is:

$w=a_{0}\left\{ x-\frac{(k-1)(k+2)}{3!}x^{3}+\frac{(k-3)(k-1)(k+2)(k+4)}{5!}x^{5}-.....\right\}$

As it is seen this is not a distinct solution. It is already available in the solution for $c=0$. Therefore, the solution for $c=0$ in my book is incomplete. Actually, it should give the complete solution as above. I learned that this happens when indicial roots differ by an integer value.

Comment: Your equation must have two linearly-independent power series solutions. $x=0$ is a regular point of the Legendre equation, not a singular point. The points $x=\pm 1$ are singular points, but not $x=0$.

Comment: I am studying this from Stroud's Advanced Engineering Math book. In the book it says Legendre's equation may be solved with Frobenius method and before that it says Frobenius method can be applied if x=0 is a regular singular point. That's why I thought x=0 is a regular singular point for Legendre's equation. There is no more knowledge in the book about irregular points or other singular points. I'd be glad if you can provide me sources about that and if the solution is wrong plese tell me (general solution is the same with the book and this means book is wrong.). @T.A.E.

Comment: Legendre's Equation has regular singular points at $x=\pm 1$, which you can see because $1-x^{2}=0$ at $x=\pm$. But all other finite points are regular points because $1-x^{2}$ does not vanish anywhere else. That means everywhere else you have two linearly-independent McClaurin series solutions. At $x=0$ there are two independent power series solutions that are guaranteed to converge in $|x| < 1$. Existence and uniqueness results are classical when all coefficients are holomorphic and the the highest order coefficient does not vanish in some neighborhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write out the solution for $c=1$ (which necessarily has no constant term and leading term $a_0 x$) and compare with what you get for your solution at $c=0$ if you *don't* assume $a_1=0$.

Comment: For $c=1$, $c(c+1)a_{1}x^{c-1}$ term should be 0. Therefore, I find $a_{1}=0$. I can't see any other relation and this is contrary.

Comment: I was being careless with notation: I meant the coefficient of the $x^1$ term. @i.ozturk

Answer (score 0):

When $c=0$, the recurrence doesn't determine $a_0$ or $a_1$. There is a two-parameter family of solutions, and you can use $a_0$ and $a_1$ as the parameters.  So you can choose $a_0$ and $a_1$ to be whatever you like.
It's  convenient to take the two basic solutions to be the ones with $(a_0,a_1) = (1,0)$ and $(0,1)$; every solution is then a linear combination of these two.

When you have a regular singular point and the indicial roots differ by an integer, there can be a logarithmic term that complicates things, but that doesn't happen in this case ($x=0$ is not a singular point).

Comment: The term: "$c(c+1)a_{1}x^{c-1}$" cannot be zero for $c=1$ unless $a_1=0$. If I take any other value for $a_1$ then the right hand side of the ode is no longer zero. I think there are limitations for $a_1$ and $a_0$ for certain values of $c$.

Comment: No.  You can take $a_1$ to be anything.  The recurrence then tells you want $a_3$ is in terms of $a_1$, what $a_5$ is in terms of $a_3$, etc.

Comment: You are right for $c=0$, but for $c=1$ I cannot take any value. I found the correct solution and edited my question. You can check that.