# Solving the Legendre Equation with Frobenius Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, legendre-polynomials

I am interested in finding two linearly independent solutions of the equation

$$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + \lambda y=0 \quad\quad (1)$$

using the Frobenius method (all the way through and not randomly deciding to take s=0 since that's just a regular power series [See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html for reference]).

We begin by writing out the needed derivatives

$$\begin{align}y =& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n x^{s+n} \\
y' =& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n (s+n) x^{s+n-1} \\
y' =& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n (s+n) (s+n-1) x^{s+n-2}\end{align}$$

and we substitute back into (1) as

$$(1-x^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n (s+n) (s+n-1) x^{s+n-2} - 2x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n (s+n) x^{s+n-1} + \lambda \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n x^{s+n}=0. $$

If we expand the first term and simplify the second term, we can rearrange to get to

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\lambda C_n - 2 C_n (s+n) - C_n(s+n)(s+n-1)\right]x^{s+n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n (s+n) (s+n-1) x^{s+n-2}=0$$

where we are left with an $x^{s+n-2}$ term.  Typically in these problems, we would rewrite that term so that it can be combined with the $x^{s+n}$ terms, usually giving us a $C_{n+2}$ term that provides the needed recurrence equation.  In a regular power series without the added power of $s$ this would simplify down nicely since we would get

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n (n) (n-1) x^{n-2} \\
\text{Let } m = n-2 \Rightarrow n = m+2 \\
\sum_{m=-2}^{\infty} C_{m+2} (m+2) (m+1) x^{m}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_{n+2} (n+2) (n+1) x^{n}$$

where we can neglect the first two terms since $n=-2$ and $n=-1$ result in the term being zero.  However, in this case, things do not simplify down nicely and we get

$$\sum_{n=-2}^{\infty} C_{n+2} (s+n+2)(s+n+1) x^{s+n}$$

where we aren't able to simplify down (that I can see).  The next step after simplifying everything down would be to group together all of the terms and require that the product of the $C_1$ term and its coefficients be equal to zero.  This will provide two values for $s$, which happen to be 0 and 1, effectively bringing us back to the original power series solution.

This problem is the same as [Solution of the Legendre's ODE using Frobenius Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873715/solution-of-the-legendres-ode-using-frobenius-method) except that question explicitly writes out the sums and then states the indicial equation.  I guess I'm missing the link between the two.  How do I simplify this problem down to get to the indicial equation?  I'm certain I'm missing something simple, but it's not quite clicking at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was definitely way overthinking this.  I believe the solution is to instead shift the first term forward rather than shifting the second term back.  This gets you to

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}C_{n-2}\left[\lambda+2(s+n-2)-(s+n-2)(s+n-3)\right]x^{s+n-2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n (s+n)(s+n-1)x^{x+n-2} = 0$$

where we then obtain the coefficients for $C_0$ from the second term where we get

$$(s)(s-1) = 0 \Rightarrow s = 0, 1$$

Everything from here is as in [Solution of the Legendre's ODE using Frobenius Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873715/solution-of-the-legendres-ode-using-frobenius-method)

I feel a bit silly now.  I think staring at equations for too long is never a good idea.